# Can't access contribution page without a login

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, contributions, contribution-page, acl

I have recently updated CiviCRM in Joomla 3.x to the latest 5.5.2 build. I'm finding on my main contribution page (used for subscriptions), that I can't access it unless I'm logged in. When logged in, it loads fine. As a public user, I get just HTML on the page, which is an error saying I can't access it. The main part of this HTML is:

```
<div class="messages status no-popup"> 
<i class="crm-i fa-exclamation-triangle crm-i-red"></i>
<span class="status-fatal">Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. 
You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.</span>
<div class="crm-section crm-error-message">You do not have permission to access this page.</div>
```

My Joomla menu item that is used in the URL for the page is set to public access. The settings for the contribution page itself haven't changed. What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check/add necessary permission that is required to access contribution page for anonymous user.

You can check by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administrator >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions (Access Control). Click on 'Joomla Access Control'.

[image]

[image]

[image]